# add a row into a database if it does not exist or update the row if it does

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to add a row into a database if it does not exist or update the row if it does. Where am I going wrong in this SQL statement?

```
UPDATE Classes 
SET (Duration='44',
INModule='Actions',
EditionsFOR='Vocus VPR - Basic    Edition//Vocus PR - Enterprise Edition//',    
Objectives='objective 1//objective 2//objective 3//', 
PreReq='prerequisite   
1//prerequisite 2//prerequisite 3//',
Points='training point   1//training point 2//training point 3//',     
ContentLink='www.aol.com', 
OtherInfo='this is the internal info', 
Summary='this is a brief summary of the class') 
WHERE Title='this is the class title' 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 
INSERT INTO Classes (Title, Duration, INModule, EditionsFOR, Objectives, PreReq, 
Points, ContentLink, OtherInfo, Summary) 
VALUES ('this is the class title','44','Actions',
'Vocus VPR - Basic Edition//Vocus PR - Enterprise Edition//',
'objective 1//objective 2//objective 3//',
'prerequisite 1//prerequisite 2//prerequisite 3//',
'training point 1//training point 2//training point 3//',
'www.aol.com','this is the internal info',
'this is a brief summary of the class')
```

Comment: What does it do? does it insert it anyway?

Comment: Nope, just fires an UPDATE syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses around `SET`. It should be written this way:

```
UPDATE Classes 
SET Duration    = '44', 
    INModule    = 'Actions', 
    EditionsFOR = 'Vocus VPR - Basic Edition//Vocus PR - Enterprise Edition//',
    Objectives  = 'objective 1//objective 2//objective       3//', 
    PreReq      = 'prerequisite 1//prerequisite 2//prerequisite 3//', 
    Points      = 'training point 1//training point 2//training point 3//', 
    ContentLink = 'www.aol.com', 
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud; this solved this UPDATE syntax error. Now it is throwing the following error:     
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Comment: Is the new syntax error on the `UPDATE` or on the `INSERT` command? Can you run the commands separately?

Comment: Running the INSERT INTO command works without a problem. Here is the returned error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Title='title of the class' IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO Classes (Title, Duration, INModule, EditionsFOR, Objectives, PreReq, Points, ContentLink, OtherInfo, Summary) VALUES ('title of the class','48','Core','Vocus VPR - Basic Edition//Vocus PR - Enterprise'.

Comment: Obviously, the data entered was slightly different here but the query remains the same.

Comment: What about just running the `UPDATE` (without `IF @@ROWCOUNT...` and `INSERT INTO...`)

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. The issue is now resolved. For your information, I am using Access as the RDMS which does not support multiple methods / queries. It also does not support @@ROWCOUNT. I had to run a select statement, see if anything came back and then run an UPDATE or INSERT INTO statement as a result, dependent on whether or not the SELECT statement returned any results. Thanks for your help. I hate it when software does not follow SQL standards properly!